# Unable to use Sitecore Forms with JSS

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms

I have followed the Sitecore Forms + JSS integration official documentation here: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/forms#sitecore-forms--jss .

But I am unable to find the `Sitecore Forms Resolver` option in the `Rendering Contents Resolver` field.

Do we need to create this content resolver with custom features/parameters?

Comment: Do you use JSS 12.0 or higher? Sitecore 9.2 or 9.3

Comment: @JanBluemink : I am using 9.1, hence got to know with the below comment as Forms are not available with JSS on 9.1.
Is there any other way to integrate forms with JSS on Sitecore 9.1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the Sitecore and JSS version you are using, JSS is compatible with the Forms after Sitecore Version 9.2 and JSS version 12. See **SXA and Sitecore Forms** compatibility table -

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra for pointing that out. I am using Sitecore 9.1, hence the forms are not working with JSS as expected.

Comment: Has Anyone tried to implement any such form implementation with Sitecore 9.1 and JSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Sitecore 10, SXA 10 and JSS 14. I have reinstalled the same  Sitecore JSS package again. This fixed my issue.

Now I can see Content Rendering Resolver -> Sitecore Form Resolver.